# Aperture control flex ribbon replacement in Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS II

Tags: lens, canon, repair, cables

Building upon [this great answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/70678/80917) to: [Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS II causes Err 01 only when zoomed beyond 135mm](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/70676/15871) I'm pretty sure that the ribbon controlling aperture inside my Canon EF-S 55-250mm lens has been damaged.  The only way I can prevent an '01 Error' is by shooting in AV mode, with the aperture set wide open.  As soon as I attempt to adjust the aperture or attempt any settings which give the camera the ability adjust it independently, I get the '01 Error'.  I could get it repaired, but I'd rather use this as an opportunity to better understand how the lens works by attempting a DIY fix. (I have other lenses so I'd rather just risk not being able to reassemble this one).

So my questions are

1. Am I correct in my reasoning regarding the underlying technical issue?
2. Does anyone know of any good tutorials (or could offer a tutorial themselves) detailing a flex cable ribbon replacement? Especially if it's related to the aperture control and especially if it's for the EF-S 55-250mm or a similar model.

Comment: Also related: [How do I disassemble my Canon 18-55mm lens to repair water damage inside it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82886/15871)